# Why do biadditive, balenced maps define a homomorphism of bimodules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

While studying Morita's theorem, I came across the following statement which really confuses me:

Let A, B be rings and $_A M_B$,$_B N_A$ be bimodules. A biadditive, $B$-balanced map $f:M\times N \rightarrow A$ defines a homomorphism of bimodules $\tilde{f}:M\otimes_BN \rightarrow A$.

Now I understand that, by the universal property of the tensor product, the map $f$ defines a homomorphism of abelian groups. I also know that the abelian group $M\otimes_BN$ can be equiped with a left and right action, turning it into an $(A,A)$-bimodule. What I don't get is why the induced morphism $\tilde{f}$ is actually a homomorphism of bimodules. Specifically, the biadditive and $B$-balanced properties of $f$ don't seem to be enough for me to be able to prove that

- $\tilde{f}(a(m\otimes n))=a\tilde{f}(m\otimes n)$
- $\tilde{f}((m\otimes n)a)=\tilde{f}(m\otimes n)a$

Moreover, wouldn't that imply that the map $f$ has the same properties on the first and second component?

Comment: Just a comment. The word you're looking for is *biadditive*. Biaddictive is not a word, but it sounds pretty funny.

Comment: Whoops... I didn't even noticed that I was compulsively writing it wrong (not just in here). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs $f(am,n)=af(m,n)$ and $f(m,na)=f(m,n)a$. Then those imply
$\tilde f(am\otimes n)=a \tilde f(m\otimes n)$ and
$\tilde f(m\otimes na)=\tilde f(m\otimes n)a$ by the definition of $\tilde f$.

Comment: Thanks! That I can understand! I've been following the book "Methods of Representation Theory" by Curtis & Reiner and they seem to state that the biaddictive and balanced properties are enough. Maybe I just interpreted it wrong...